# How to read Child Tags in XML file with VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to get an output from a VBScript that is reading only 1 XML file.
This XML file is located at C:\scripts\license.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<License xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XM LSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/License.xsd">
<Network>
<NetworkName>TestName</NetworkName>
<NetworkID>29</NetworkID>
<Region>1</Region>
<MaxDisplays>375</MaxDisplays>
<Expiry>2017-05-25</Expiry>
<Issued>2016-12-11</Issued>
<Communicator>ZZ007007007</Communicator>
```

I want to use VBScript for Zabbix Monitoring the Expiry tag in the xml file.

```
Dim licDate
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")  
xmlDoc.load("C:\scripts\license.xml")   

licDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Expiry").item(0).text

itemInfo= licDate
MsgBox itemInfo
```

Can't seem to get this code working.
I get the error: Object required: 'xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(...).item(...)'

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the remarks section for `getElementsByTagName` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762212(VS.85).aspx):

> The `getElementsByTagName` method simulates the matching of the provided argument against the result of the `tagName` property of `IXMLDOMElement`. When executed, it does not recognize or support namespaces. Instead, you should use the `selectNodes` method, which is faster in some cases and can support more complex searches.

You therefore have two choices - do as the documentation states, or loop through each tag manually.

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:default='http://tempuri.org/License.xsd'"
Set expiry = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//default:Expiry")
Wscript.Echo expiry.text
```

> 2017-05-25

---

```
Set nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
For index = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Set element = nodeList.item(index)
    If element.tagName = "Expiry" Then
        Wscript.Echo element.text
    End If
Next
```